# Showing dynamic content inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat, q

Struggling to show dynamic content inside a `ngRepeat`. When it comes time to show my promise content, I'm getting an empty object `{}`:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div class="sidebar" ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="name">{{row.name}}</div>
            <div class="title">{{map[$index]}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
 function DemoCtrl($scope, $http, $q) {
    const rows = function() {
        const rows = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            rows.push({
                id: `demo-${i}`,
                name: `Demo ${i}`
            });
        }

        return rows;
    };

    $scope.rows = rows();
    $scope.map = [];

    // $scope.$watch($scope.map, function (oldValue, newValue) {
    //   console.log(oldValue, newValue);
    // });

    function _data() {
        // const promises = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.rows.length; i++) {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i + 1}`).then(function(post) {
                defer.resolve(`${post.data.title.substring(0, 10)}...`);
            });

            $scope.map.push(defer.promise);
            // promises.push(defer.promise);
        }

        // return $q.all(promises);
        return $q.all($scope.map);
    }

    function _init() {
        _data().then(function(data) {
            $scope.map = data; // why aren't we getting here?
        });
    };

    _init();
}
```

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2BMfIU97Moisir7BBPNc

I've tinkered with some other ideas such as trying to add a `$watch` on the `$scope` object after the value changes, but I'm not convinced this will help in any way. Some lingering questions I have:

1. From what I understand, you can use a [promise inside a template](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) so how/why does this change inside a `ngRepeat`?
2. Why isn't my callback for `$q.all` getting called?
3. If this is not the right approach, what is?

Comment: I think that you can add `ng-if` to `ng-repeat` div and a condition, that `rows.length > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you will almost never need to use $q.

You can simply fill an array of posts titles after each $http.get

```
function DemoCtrl($scope, $http) {
  const rows = function () {
    const rows = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      rows.push({
        id: `demo-${i}`,
        name: `Demo ${i}`
      });
    }

    return rows;
  };

  $scope.rows = rows();
  $scope.map = [];

  function _init() {
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.rows.length; i++) {

      $http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i + 1}`).then(function (post) {
        $scope.map.push(post.data.title);
      });
    }
  }

  _init();
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zOF4KNtAIFqoCOfinaMO?p=preview

Comment: I'm aware `$q` is rarely needed, but poorly-written legacy code warrants it in my case. Thanks for for the solution